# How to broadcast push notification to multiple devices using react-native-push-notification and Firebase?

Tags: react-native

I want to broadcast notification to multiple devices instead of adding FCM token of each device. Currently, I am sending notification using Firebase cloud messaging to send a notification but in that, I have to add FCM client token for each device, but what I want is to broadcast message without collecting client device FCM Token.

Following versions are being used in my app
'''
"react-native": "0.55.4",
"react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.3",
'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to options:

**Option1:**

You can create a device group and send push notifcations to a group of devices. Read more in the docs [iOS device-group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/device-group) and [Android device-group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group). Of course, here you need to know the id of the group.

**Option2:**

Create a topic, where your devices need to subscribe to. Then you can publish directly on topics. Unfortunately subscribing to topics is only supported for android when using `react-native-push-notification`, see [react-native-push-notification#android-only-methods](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#android-only-methods)

Answer (score 0):

As originally answered by [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6278661/tim) you have two options.

If you don't mind changing your notification library, you can use `react-native-firebase`. It covers most of the available Firebase features and is well-maintained.

Here's the setup guide for subscribing to [topics](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/topics)

Comment: how can I send notification to user login devices Like iPhone, iPad, desktop, android. all 4 devices send notification in a single click.